# What does "N" mean for an igraph object in R?

Tags: r, igraph

I use igraph package in R and create a simple graph named `g`. In the first row of the output using `str(g)`, I figured the first letter can be U or D for undirected and directed graphs. The third letter can be W for weighted graph. The fourth letter can be B for bipartite graph.

**What does the second letter mean?** Hopefully my understanding is right for the other three letters. I tried the igraph help file but can't find an answer. Thanks.

```
> g <- graph.formula(1-2, 1-3, 1-4, 2-4)
> str(g)
IGRAPH UN-- 4 4 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c)
+ edges (vertex names):
[1] 1--2 1--3 1--4 2--4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**N** is for *named* graph. See `?is.named`.
And yes for the other three letters.

Documentation: see details in `?str.igraph` or `?print.igraph`